# How to create a class with properties using RDFlib

Tags: python, rdf, owl, ontology, rdflib

I am trying to develop an ontology using Python RDFLib. I am new to python and RDFlib,    Can anyone provide a simple example of how I can create a class, adding properties to that class, create object/individual of that class. I have developed the same application in java using Jena API,     I could have created datatype properties and object type properties for classes by using Jena API. Can we do the same by using RDFLib? Thanks in advance

Comment: for OWL, owlready2 would be the more OWL oriented API. For RDFLib, just add RDF triples. The docs are online and show how to add data to the RDF graph in RDFLib: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Thanks bro, But I tried OWLready already and i felt very difficult to install that, they werre keep asking visual c++ distribution, My question is how to create class and its object in RDFReady

Comment: and I showed you the link to the docs for RDFLib. they explain how to add RDF triples to the graph, or not? And creating an instance with some class and proeprties assigned is nothing more than adding RDF triples, or not?

Comment: You seem to think in terms of object orientation. You can have a look at my [blog](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/mathematical-formalization-of-object-orientation/) for how OWL relates to object orientation.

Comment: So, are we saying, we cannot use rdflib to create classes?

Comment: No, But I used OWLReady2 for my project,I felt that more simple and easy to handle, Please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Hi Thanks for your all support, I have installed owlready 2 through anaconda by using this command conda install -c conda-forge owlready2
[https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/owlready2][1]

I can easilly create classes and individual using OWLReady2

```
 from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology("http://elearning.org/onto.owl")

"""Functions to create Ontology class"""
with onto:
 class Student(Thing):
       pass
 class LearningMaterial(Thing):
      pass
 class readBook(ObjectProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range  = [LearningMaterial]
 class Age(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[str]
 class Gender(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[str]
 class Qualification(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[str] 
 class Branch(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[str]
 class Background_Knowledge(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[str]
 class Active_Reflective(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[str] 
 class AR_Value(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[int] 
 class Sensitive_Intutive(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[str]
 class S_I_Value(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[int]
 class Visual_Verbal(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[str]
 class S_I_Value(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[int]
  class S_I_Value(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[int]
  class S_I_Value(DataProperty):
  domain = [Student]
  range=[int]
 def createStudentIndividual(stud):
  """This method will create Student Object"""
  studobj=Student(stud[0], namespace = onto, Age = [stud[1]],
  Gender=[stud[2]],Qualification=[stud[3]],Branch=[stud[4]],
  Background_Knowledge=[stud[5]],Active_Reflective=[stud[6]]
  ,AR_Value=[stud[7]],Sensitive_Intutive=[stud[8]],S_I_Value=[stud[9]])

#save ontology to a File
def saveOntology():
 onto.save(file = "learnsystem.owl", format = "rdfxml")

createStudentIndividual(["Ratheesh",'19','1','2','3','3','3',3,'3',3,3]) 

saveOntology()
```